# Compress an image without specifying the type of image

Tags: java

This code is to compress a jpeg image, but if I want to compress an image without specifying the type of image, how can I do that? , How do I modify the code ?

```
   File originalImage = new File("C:\\Users\\Super\\Desktop\\man.jpg");
   File compressedImage = new File("C:\\Users\\Super\\Desktop\\compressedImage.jpg");
   try{
       compressJPEGImage(originalImage, compressedImage,0.5f );
       System.out.println("Done!");
   }
   catch(IOException e){
       
   }
   }
   public static void compressJPEGImage(File originalImage , File compressedImage , float 
    compressionQuality) throws IOException{
    RenderedImage image = ImageIO.read(originalImage);
    ImageWriter jpegwriter = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg").next();
    ImageWriteParam jpegWriteParam=jpegwriter.getDefaultWriteParam();
    jpegWriteParam.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
    jpegWriteParam.setCompressionQuality(compressionQuality);
    try(ImageOutputStream output=ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(compressedImage)){
        jpegwriter.setOutput(output);
        IIOImage outputImage = new IIOImage(image,null,null);
        jpegwriter.write(null,outputImage,jpegWriteParam);
    }
jpegwriter.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Note your current code does not care about the original format.

Comment: I don't understand , can you tell me what do you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

Convert image to base64 or byte array of any type, then you can try for compressing it.

Comment: Even if you convert the image to base64, its type will remain the same. The question is how to compress an image of any type ?